# mongoose Проблемы с сохранением схемы

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Во-первых хочу прояснить почему не срабатывает данный код, так как почти аналогичный работает.

```
    User.findById(_user._id, (err,user)=>{
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    for (let i = 0; i < user.own_collections.length; i++){
         if(user.own_collections[i]._id == collection._id){
            user.own_collections[i].words.push(newWord);
            console.log('user', user.own_collections[0]);
            user.save(callback);
         }

    }
});
```

Функция push срабатывает нормально, так как в консоле выводится обновлённый объект.

Во-вторых: я понимаю что так как я осуществил поиск это не правильно, так что прошу совета как это можно организовать правильно.
Чтобы бы было понятнее что надо:
Имеется такой объект (пользователь)`{
  "_id": "58f379e71a2f1660daa015a4",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "username": "Pierre Deuj",
  "password": "$2a$10$8Wifui1/mjjq36IML7bLFuseXk5Iun5eTDbsdnX2XIzDaqQAnghL2",
  "own_collections": [
    {
      "name": "new collection",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "_id": "58f4b3521910ee0734404d34",
      "words": [
        {
          "english": "lorem",
          "russian": "ипсум",
          "example": "",
          "_id": "58f4db84f123fa455b520235"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "new collection1",
      "description": "lorem ipsum",
      "_id": "58f4b3741910ee0734404d3e",
      "words": []
    }
  ],
  "added_collections": [
    "58f376eeb553965cd3c3a19b"
  ],
  "__v": 54
}`

так вот надо произвести поиск такого вида:
1)Сначала найти этого пользователя - это я умею (findOne / findById);
2)У этого пользователя есть поле own_collections;
3)В поле own_collections необходимо найти объект (по id или ещё как-то неважно);
4)В поле words этого объекта добавить(push) другой объект

Буду благодарен за любую помощь, хочу понять как правильно работать с mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте проверку, есть ли у user.own_collections[i] ключ words, иначе сервак вообще закрашится с ошибкой cannot ... .push() of undefined.
Для поиска ключа можно юзать функцию по типу indexOf(), выводящую позицию, если такой ключ есть и -1, если ключ (words) не найден:

```
function containsItem(key, obj) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(key)
}
```

И

```
   User.findById(_user._id, (err,user)=>{
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        for (let i = 0; i < user.own_collections.length; i++){
             if(user.own_collections[i]._id == collection._id){
                if(containsItem('words', user.own_collections[i])) {
                    user.own_collections[i].words.push(newWord);
                    console.log('user', user.own_collections[0]); 
                } else {
                   user.own_collections[i].push({"words": newWord})
                }
                user.save(callback);
             }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Вот что вываливается в консоль: `user { name: 'new collection1413',
  description: 'lorem ipsum',
  _id: '58f63fcb901461499dcd8981',
  words: 
   [ { _id: 58f89b9b44bb78216032cd0b,
       example: '',
       russian: 'lввфввффвф12312',
       english: 'dadadad231da111111111111111111111111111111' } ] }`
,но в бд изменений нет как и раньше. callback срабатывает, никаких ошибок нет

Comment: А выведите в консоль не 0-ой элемент, а все в цикле, выведите также, есть ли у него ключ "words":

console.log(user.own_collections[i].hasOwnProperty("words"));
console.log(user.own_collections[i]);

Comment: console.log(user.own_collections[i].hasOwnProperty('words'));  - true. Поле words есть всегда, в mongoui всё смотрю. До push это пустой массив, после появляется 1 элемент который мы добавили, но save(callback) - этот самый callback вызывает и всё, сохранения в бд нет. Хотя есть почти аналогичный метод где всё прекрасно сохраняется,даже 2.

Comment: Причём если добавить (push) этот объект на уровень ниже: user.own_collections.push(newWord); В тот массив где должны быть коллекции, всё отлично сохраняется. То есть проблема именно в добавлении в массив words[]

Comment: А что у вас callback?

Comment: response клиенту

Comment: выведите консолью до пуша console.log(user.own_collections[i].words) и после пуша и посмотрите, чё там, может поможет

Comment: До пуша там пусто, после тот Object что и должен сохранятьсяю

Comment: попробуйте отловить ошибку:
user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error in Saving dialog: ' + err);
                throw err;
            } else {....

А ещё, через что вы смотрите содержимое бд?

Comment: Никаких ошибок при сохранении не выдаёт, смотрю через mongoui